# How to inspect the data of an MBtile

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

I'd like to be able to inspect the actual data that is contained in an individual MapBox vector tile to help debug some issues I'm having with my vector tile server which can't be resolved just by visually looking at the tile in mapbox.js.

What are some ways to go about this? Ideally I'd like to just open file in my editor and inspect it.

I tried using [mapbox_vector-tile-js](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js) but it keeps saying the tiles have no layers despite the tiles rendering fine in mapbox.js.

Perhaps I am using it incorrectly (code below), but still, I'd just prefer to see the tile's details in my text editor.

I'm downloading the vector tiles like so:

`wget  http://localhost:8080/maps/osm/12/1206/123.pbf`

Then trying the following:

```js
const file = "123.pbf"
fs.readFile(file, 'binary', function(err, pbfdata){  
  var pbf = new Pbf(pbfdata)
  var tile = new VectorTile(pbf);
  console.log(tile.layers);   // => {} i.e. empty
})


// also tried
zlib.gunzip(file, function(err, pbfdata) {
  var pbf = new Pbf(pbfdata)
  var tile = new VectorTile(pbf);
  console.log(tile.layers);  // => {} i.e. empty
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An .mbtiles is "just" a SQLite database!

Though the actual map data seems to be some kind of opaque binary encoding, you can get metadata about the layers:

```sql
sh> sqlite3 mymaps.mbtiles

sqlite> select json(vector_layer.value) -> '$.id' from metadata, json_each(metadata.value, '$.vector_layers') as vector_layer where name = 'json';
json(vector_layer.value) -> '$.id'
"aerodrome_label"
"aeroway"
"boundary"
"building"
"housenumber"
"landcover"
"landuse"
"mountain_peak"
"park"
"place"
"poi"
"transportation"
"transportation_name"
"water"
"water_name"
"waterway"
```

Comment: The question is about exactly that "kind of opaque binary encoding" though ;)